# Remove content type from "New" item options?

Tags: 2010, content-type, item

I need to migrate some values into SharePoint that would have useless values for our system going forward. I'm using a content type called "Old Request" solely so that they can have different columns and clearly be identified as such. I want to have "New Request" and "Old Request" within the same list, but I don't my users to be able to create a "New Old Request" for obvious reasons :)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the content type hidden by using PowerShell: Example:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity http://aissp2013:111
$list = $web.Lists["TestList"]
$list.ContentTypes["TestCT"].Hidden = $true
$list.ContentTypes["TestCT"].Update()
```

**UPDATE**

However, the above code or the steps given by @Robert will not hide Content Type dropdown from Edit page. That can be done by placing a script in Content Editor web part:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // Hides the entire table row from the EditForm.aspx
        $('select[id*="Content Type"]').parent().parent().hide();
    });
</script>
```

Reference: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/29cf0091-6d2e-413b-b6b2-b376f51ee972/how-to-disableinvisible-content-type-drop-down-for-custom-document-librarys-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

Comment: I implemented the change and then ran into the issue that you just mentioned in the update. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 7):

In the Document Library (or List) settings:

1. Under the section "Content Types" click "Change new button order and default content type"
2. Uncheck "Visible" for the Content Type you want to hide
3. Click OK